How do browsers render text using any font, any modifier (like bold, italic...) so fast?
Background:
I am implementing a 2d renderer using OpenGL and currently working on rendering text.
What I have so far:

you can generate bitmap fonts from given font files (like .ttf). It works by rasterizing a bitmap for each glyph and getting glyph data (using the FreeType library). It then combines the bitmaps into a large texture atlas + a json file containing glyph data.

when you want to render a font, you'd load the json, that will in turn load the font's texture atlas. Then, it will render a textured quad for every character. (Note: it is not rendering directly but rather pushing vertices to a buffer, which is rendered when it is flush()ed).

you can also generate SDF (signed distance fields) for every character if you would like to render large text - but it uses a dedicated shader.

currently, I don't use a dedicated layout engine but that's a planned feature (Harfbuzz + ICU4U).


Question
How do browsers render text immediately?
It seems like I can throw whatever font, whatever modifier, scale, you name it - and the text will always render fast and crisp. It surely doesn't seem like a bitmap is generated for every scale or modifier.

A technique that works for the browser won't always be an appropriate technique for a game. You'll also find more game programmers on this site than browser programmers, so most folks who find your post and could help with your game won't necessarily know how browsers do it in detail, meaning they're excluded from answering by the question's current framing. I'd recommend asking "How can I achieve fast font rendering in my game" to get suggestions for game-optimized techniques, like SDFs, dynamic font atlases, or Eric Lengyel's proprietary Slug font rendering algorithm.

@DMGregory It might be good to go into a bit of detail about why the technique that a browser uses isn't suitable for a game.

Some factors that may be relevant include latency (web page display time is dominated by network round trip and download speeds, so spending tens of milliseconds on font rendering may be acceptable, whereas that could exceed our target frame time in games), workload allocation (most of a browser's job is displaying a document, so it can devote most of its memory / CPU / GPU to this; in games we may have thousands of meshes, textures, game rules, and agent behaviours competing for those resources), and variability (games usually know the handful of font styles and sizes they need in advance).
